# How to determine if there is a support for NVMe

Tags: ssd, pci-express, nvme

[image]I have Acer Aspire 3 A315-53G, I want to upgrade my laptop with m.2 SSD. There is a slot for it but the manual of laptop doesn't provide any info on it, I asked official support but the answers are somewhat conflicting. There are some other configurations with the same model, some have dedicated GPU and some don't, in my case it comes with dedicated GPU that uses PCIe 3.0x4. Laptop supports SATA m.2 but not sure if it supports NVMe. How can I check if it supports? m.2 is M key

HWInfo report:

[image]

- 4x PCIe3.0 is used by GPU
- 1x PCIe1.0 is used by Ethernet and SDCard reader
- 1x PCIe1.0 is used by wifi

UPDATE

I bought HP EX900 250Gb NVMe drive and it worked! Thank you for the help!

Comment: M key typically means PCIe/NVME. B key would be SATA.

Comment: if it says it supports a SATA m.2 with no indication of NVMe then chances are it ONLY supports SATA. Having a PCIe GPU is irrelevant to whether you have an m.2 NVMe slot, usually the GPU is soldered on.

Comment: why i mention having a gpu because hwinfo reports having PCIe 3.0x4 which gpu is using all 4 lanes and PCIe 1.0x2 which ethernet port and sdcard reader are using. There is no indication of free lanes in hwinfo. I am really confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An opposing indication is from the
[Crucial Upgrade Advisor](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/acer/aspire-3-a315-53g)
which doesn't offer any NVMe disk upgrade for your model.
The offered upgrades are all SATA.

I suggest to install the
[Crucial System Scanner](https://www.crucial.com/)
for a hardware scan and a final opinion.

Whatever disk you buy, I would advice only buying from a vendor
with a good return policy.

---

(*Old answer which I suspect was wrong*)

According to user testimony at the post
[NVMe supported or not? Acer aspire 3 A315-53G](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/626947/nvme-supported-or-not-acer-aspire-3-a315-53g),
NVMe is indeed supported.

Actually in this post, the initial comment was negative, and the poster
then bought a lower-performance disk, so was quite disgruntled.

Comment: So, there is no easy way to determine this in a general way? i.e. it is hardware specific, is it?

Comment: I reversed my answer above.

Comment: does HWInfo report unused pcie lanes?